# x86_64 ASM - maximum bytes for an instruction?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, 64-bit, x86-64

What is the maximum number of bytes a complete instruction would require in x64 asm code?

Something like a jump to address might occupy up to 9 bytes I suppose: **FF 00 00 00 00 11 12 3F 1F** but I don't know if that's the maximum number of bytes a x64 instruction can use

Comment: [The longest possible instruction on x86 is 15 bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set)

Comment: Note that, while it's possible to construct a single instruction that should be longer than 15 bytes (by using a bunch of prefixes), the x86 instruction decoder frontend will choke on it. 15 bytes is a hard limit.

Comment: @duskwuff: Intel manual says "Up to four prefixes of 1 bytes each". So, by the spec, I suppose that the decoder should reject instructions with more than four prefixes even if the instruction is shorter than 15 bytes in total. Didn't test it though.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The x86 instruction set (16, 32 or 64 bit, all variants/modes) guarantees / requires that instructions are at most 15 bytes. Anything beyond that will give an "invalid opcode". You can't achieve that without using redundant prefixes (e.g. multiple 0x66 or 0x67 prefixes, for example).

The only instruction that actually takes 64-bits as a data item is the load constant to register (Intel syntax: `mov reg, 12345678ABCDEF00h`, at&t syntax: `movabs $12345678ABCDEF00, %reg`) - so if you wanted to jump more than 31 bits forward/backward, it would be a move of the target location into a register, and then call/jump to the register.  Using 32-bit immediates and displacements (in relative jumps and addressing modes) saves four bytes on many instructions in 64-bit mode.

Comment: There are also forms of `mov` which can take a full 64-bit address, those which take `moffs`'s as a operand. But they can only move to/from the accumulator, so the maximum useful length for them is still only  11 bytes (8 for the address, 1 for the opcode, 1 for a 64- or 16-bit operand size, and 1 for a fs or gs segment override).

Comment: Just as an aside Computer Architecture A Quantitative Approach has said 17 and now in the 6th edition says 18 bytes (p. 14). Intel says 15 and I'm sticking with 15.

Comment: @Olsonist: It is possible to invent cases where an instruction without any redundant or inapplicable prefixes could require more than 15 bytes to encode.  Such instructions are not encodeable and do fault (tested on Skylake, Linux delivers SIGSEGV not SIGILL); you'll have to find another way to solve your problem, e.g. `lea` an address or `mov` an immediate into a register first.  It's not easy to come up with real plausible cases, e.g. `fs xacquire lock add qword [r8d + edx + 1234], 0x1234` would be 16 bytes if it were valid.  (NASM and YASM both unfortunately assemble it without a warning).

Answer (score 31):

> **Questions is**, what’s the longest possible instruction in the x86 instruction set?
>
> **Answer:** you can form a valid x86 instruction with an **infinite number of bytes!**
>
> That’s right, *you could fill up an entire 64K ROM image with a single valid instruction*. To be more specific, there is no limit to the length of 8086 instructions.  Cool! Unfortunately, modern day i386 variants throw a general protection fault when attempting to decode instructions longer than 15 bytes.
>
> So what does an infinitely-long-but-valid 8086 instruction look like?  Kinda boring, actually.  You could only form an infinitely long instruction by using redundant prefixes in front on the opcodes.  Instruction prefixes are bytes pre-pended to the beginning of an instruction that can modify the default address size, data size, or segment registers used by an instruction.
>
> For example, you can take the innocuous looking instruction:
>
> ```
> 89 E5              mov %sp,%bp
> ```
>
> And turn it into a really long instruction:
>
> ```
> 66 66 66 66 … 66 66 89 E5                mov %sp,%bp
> ```
>
> Now that’s just evil.

https://web.archive.org/web/20131109063453/https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/blog/?p=23

---

## Another long instruction without repeating prefixes

> In some cases it is possible to encode valid instructions that exceed the traditional 15-byte length limit. For example:
>
> ```
>   ; 16-bit mode
>   F2 F0 36 66 67 81 84 24 disp32 imm32 =  xaquire lock add [ss:esp*1+disp32],imm32
>   F3 F0 36 66 67 81 84 24 disp32 imm32 = xrelease lock add [ss:esp*1+disp32],imm32
>
>   ; 16-bit mode
>   36 67 8F EA 78 12 84 24 disp32 imm32 = lwpins eax,[ss:esp*1+disp32],imm32
>   36 67 8F EA 78 12 8C 24 disp32 imm32 = lwpval eax,[ss:esp*1+disp32],imm32
>   36 67 8F EA 78 10 84 24 disp32 imm32 =  bextr eax,[ss:esp*1+disp32],imm32
>
>   ; 64-bit mode
>   64 67 8F EA F8 12 84 18 disp32 imm32 = lwpins rax,[fs:eax+ebx+disp32],imm32
>   64 67 8F EA F8 12 8C 18 disp32 imm32 = lwpval rax,[fs:eax+ebx+disp32],imm32
>   64 67 8F EA F8 10 84 18 disp32 imm32 =  bextr rax,[fs:eax+ebx+disp32],imm32
> ```

http://www.sandpile.org/x86/opc_enc.htm

Comment: The instruction set imposed no limit on instruction length. The limit is defined by the instruction decoder

Comment: The ISA for 386 and later does impose a 15-byte limit.  286 imposed a 10-byte limit.  The "infinite" insn length thing only works on 8086, not x86 (or x86-64), not even a modern x86 CPU in real mode.  The second half of your answer should say "otherwise-valid".  You left out the bottom of that footnote, which says **It is up to the user to avoid these cases (and the resulting #GP exception).**

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : whith which assembler dos you assemble`lwpins rax,[fs:eax+ebx+disp32],imm32`? gnu as doesn’t recognize this.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc You chose a particularly bad example as `lwpins` never made it into silicone. Though, I don't know af any other overly long instructions; VEX mitigated this problem pretty well.

Answer (score 24):

From the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual:

> **2.3.11 AVX Instruction Length**
>
> The maximum length of an Intel 64 and IA-32 instruction remains 15
>   bytes.

You can construct instructions that would encode to more than 15 bytes, but such instructions would be illegal and would probably not execute.

Comment: Indeed, real CPUs raise a #GP exception when they don't get to the end of an instruction within 15 bytes from the first prefix.  I didn't check if this behaviour is guaranteed on paper in Intel's and/or AMD's manuals.