# Examining memory with x86 proccesor

Tags: c, gdb

I'm new in GDB and have some problem with it. I have x86 proccesor and it means that register eip in my proccesor should contain 4 byte memory. I compiled some c code and set break point to main(). Typing x/x $eip gives me back "0xd02404c7"(hexadecimal) which as i know is some instruction to machine language. So my questions is: if This machine instruction is the size of 4 byte. This command  "x/4x $eip" should display 16 byte and it show me this:

```
0x8048426 <main+9>: 0xd02404c7  0xe8080484  0xfffffebe  0x9066c3c9
```

So i'm confused. If this is 16 byte than why does it show me that it is located on the same memory when 1 register in 32 bit proccesor should contain only 4 byte? Thank you.

Comment: x86 opcodes are not always four bytes (infact are very rarely four bytes). `eip` doesn't store the current instruction, it stores the *address* of the current instruction.

Comment: so basically "0xd02404c7  0xe8080484  0xfffffebe  0x9066c3c9" these are addresses of insturctions right? I'm confused doesn't it mean that when proccesor is x86 its registers maximum memory is 4 byte?

Comment: The registers are a max of four bytes, yes, but `$eip` stores the *address* of the next instruction, not the actual next instruction. What you are seeing in your output is the address of the instruction (on the left), then four words of instruction. Consider using `disassemble $eip` instead to show the opcode.

Comment: ohhh. Now i get it. Thank you very very much. And one more question please. So every memory address can store 4 machine instructions?

Answer (score 2):

> Typing x/x $eip gives me back "0xd02404c7"(hexadecimal) which as i know is some instruction to machine language.

No, it gives you *raw* bytes in your code. These raw bytes can "cover" less than one, one, or several machine instructions. A shortest x86 instruction takes up just one byte. The longest instruction [takes 15 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14698559/50617).

> So my questions is: if This machine instruction is the size of 4 byte.

An address is 4 bytes, but the instruction itself may contain 1 to 15 bytes. You can see the relationship between bytes and instructions if you do `(gdb) disas/r main`

> So every memory address can store 4 machine instructions?

Not at all. Every memory address corresponds to 1 byte of memory. That byte may contain an entire (single-byte) instruction, or it can be a start of multi-byte instruction, or it could not contain any instructions at all (if the address points to e.g. `.data` section).