# x86-64 duplicate instruction prefix

Tags: assembly, cpu, disassembly

Opcode prefix can be duplicated. For example, let's take 8B opcode (mov) with operand size override prefix:

```
66 66 66 66 66 8B 00
```

visual studio disassembler's output (x64 mode):

```
mov ax, word ptr [rax]
```

Now, let's take this one:

```
66 66 66 66 67 8B 00
```

visual studio disassembler's output:

```
mov ax, word ptr [eax]
```

And this one:

```
66 66 66 67 /*it throws away left side*/ 67 8B 00
```

visual studio disassembler's output:

```
??
??
??
??
mov eax, dword ptr [eax]
```

So, I want to ask why prefix 67 can't be duplicated. Is it visual studio specific processing that does not match hardware semantics or cpu itself does not allow this?

Comment: Duplicating prefixes is undefined behavior. That said, I don't know why the VS disassemble does what it does. `ndisasm` and `objdump`, for example, decode that as expected.

Comment: ["You could only form an infinitely long instruction by using redundant prefixes in front on the opcodes"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18972014/995714). "For example, you can take the innocuous looking instruction: `89 E5 mov %sp,%bp` and turn it into a really long instruction: `66 66 66 66 … 66 66 89 E5 mov %sp,%bp`"

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc You can't have infinite prefixes. While I don't believe duplicate "classic" prefixes results in undefined behaviour, gas uses them for long NOPs, a total instruction length greater than 15 does.

Answer (score 1):

It seems VS simply does not support this. With ndisasm (the disassembler of nasm), it just works well, it is diassembled as:

```
6767668B00        mov ax,[eax]
```

The problem with this is however, in a normal 64 bit environment, addressing using only the lower 32 bit is normally not possible.

But I tested with:

```
 67674889D8        mov rax,rbx
```

and the CPU (i7-4770) executed it without an exception.