# How to get opcode of instruction using qemu (size parameter of function cpu_memory_rw_debug() )?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, qemu, opcode

I would like to get the opcode of an i386 instruction that is executed in my QEMU guest. I found that `cpu_memory_rw_debug(env, pc, buf, size, is_write);` can access the memory. Yet, I don't know how much memory I have to read. In other words, what value to assign to `size`. I learned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698350/x86-64-asm-maximum-bytes-for-an-instruction) SO post that the

> x86 instruction set (16, 32 or 64 bit, all variants/modes) is guaranteed to fit in 15 bytes

If I read 15 bytes each time, I need to somehow determine where the opcode ends, because most opcodes are less than 15 bytes.

I guess there must be a qemu function for this.
There is probably a better qemu feature to do what I want without fiddling with opcodes lengths. Unfortunately, I couldn't find either of the two.

A I missing something conceptually?

All hints are appreciated.

Comment: Determining the length of an x86 instruction is hard; you have to decode prefixes until you get to the opcode, which itself is variable length (escape bytes, and can include 3 bits from the mod/rm field for one-operand insns like `not`).  The operand-size prefix changes the length of the rest of an instruction with an immediate.  (`add r32, imm32` vs. `add r16, imm16`: this LCP case actually stalls the decoders in Intel hardware).  IDK qemu internals, but looking for a qemu function that decodes x86 instructions sounds like a much better idea than writing one yourself.

Comment: Much better question is, what do you want to do with that information.

Comment: @Jester I would like to store all executed instructions (i.e. their opcodes) into a file. In other words, I want to create an execution instruction trace of my QEMU guest. I don't want to use the QEMU monitor because I need more information than the monitor provides. This is why I use PANDA, a qemu-based tool which provides me more info and also allows to combine it with public qemu functions such at `cpu_memory_rw_debug()`

Comment: @PeterCordes What do you mean by 'IDK qemu internals, ...' ? IDK? You are right that looking for a corresponding qemu function is the way to go, but I could not find any. Do you have a hint for me?

Comment: you will determine instruction end only when you decode it byte by byte. capturing often redundant 15 bytes is most simple way if you have a sufficient memory for that.