# What is the maximum length an Intel 386 instruction without any prefixes?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, machine-code, instruction-set

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698350/x86-64-asm-maximum-bytes-for-an-instruction), but I need to know what is the longest instruction length on Intel 386(which is 32-bit not 64 bit) without using any instruction prefixes.

Based on the manual, it is probably 12:

- Opcode: 2 bytes
- MOD/Rm: 1 byte
- SIB: 1 byte
- Displacement: 4 bytes
- Immediate: 4 bytes
- Total: 12

Is this the correct answer?

Comment: The linked answer says that the processor will throw an exception for instructions that are more than 15 bytes. Why is that not good enough for you?

Comment: Technically opcode can be 3 bytes, but currently I don't think any such instruction takes a 4 byte immediate so you can't have both to get up to 13 bytes (without prefix).

Comment: @ user3386109: Because I don't know how you can build a 15 byte instruction without using prefixes. 15 is the upper bound, but I don't think is the tightest upper bound when prefixes are not allowed.

Comment: Instruction prefixes are a part of the instruction, effectively additional bits of the opcode, Mod/RM, and/or SIB bytes. You can't ignore or disallow them like they aren't important.

Comment: @RossRidge: I did not say they are not important, but one can imagine an implementation of a subset of x86 ISA in which prefixes are not supported.

Comment: @Ari I can't. With no operand size prefix you've lost many SIMD (SSE) instructions and most 16-bit (or 32-bit) instructions. With no REX prefixes you've lost all 64-bit instructions. With no segment overrides real mode doesn't work, and neither does thread local storage. With no REP prefixes you've lost the string instructions and a bunch more SIMD instructions.

Comment: @RossRidge: I have mentioned in my question that this is related to x86-32 bit, not 64 bit. I should have been more specific, I am only interested in 386 ISA, which doesn't have SIMD instructions or multi-threading. Regardless, I don't see why this question seems unrelated. One can write valid 386 programs -albeit with some limitation- without using any prefixes.

Comment: Are you counting the opcode length including the "escape codes" (repurposed prefix bytes) that are effectively part of the opcode for long vector instructions?  e.g. `PMOVZXBW xmm1, xmm2/m64` is encoded as `66 0f 38 30 /r`.  These long opcodes have at most 8bits of immediate data, though, so I guess it doesn't help anyway.

Comment: So, you've only lost 16-bit (or 32-bit) instructions, real mode, tread local storage (which is supported by the '386), and string instructions. Losing 16-bit instructions alone is crippling. What do you think your restricted instruction set is actually good for?

Comment: @RossRidge No, the 16/32 bit instructions can still be supported by using the D-bit of the code-segment descriptor. Also, multithreading AFAIK is not supported by 386. Multitasking is. The prefixes supported by 386 are segment override, address size, operand size, and REP/lock. Anyway, I am not really trying to justify such an implementation here. I think my question is now clear enough...

Comment: @PeterCordes: No, those instructions are not part of 386 ISA.

Comment: @RossRidge: I think it's a moderately interesting question.  I wouldn't bother trying to justify it as a useful subset of the 386 ISA, though.  That actually makes it *less* interesting. :P  Also, IDK why you'd restrict it to just 386.  Since as I pointed out, there aren't any vector instructions that can take large immediate constants, so they end up not being part of the picture.  I flipped through Intel's insn ref manual and didn't see anything.  The non-prefix *part* of `mov r64, imm64` is 9 bytes, and the whole 10B instruction requires a REX prefix to distinguish it from `mov r32, imm32`.

Comment: You expect the hypothetical program to jump to a 16-bit code segment to perform 16-bit operations and then back to 32-bit code segment to perform 32-bit operations? That's worse than just using multiple 8-bit instructions (though might be necessary to access 16-bit and 32-bit device registers that must be accessed in a single instruction.) Operating systems like Windows NT, Windows 95 and Linux supported threads on '386 CPUs. You haven't make it clear why your question is actually useful. It seems like a pointless thought experiment with no practical application.

Comment: @RossRidge: "thought experiment with no practical application".  That's what I think it is, and I still up-voted it.  I'm not curious enough to figure out how to exhaustively check that the OP's 12B upper bound is correct, though :P  I was surprised an insn could get that big without prefixes, but it makes sense.  It shows more research effort than the usual "I don't know asm, and here's my homework assignment" questions.

Comment: @RossRidge: The usability of such an implementation is subjective, but for applications that only need a subset of original features (eg. supporting only 16 or only 32 bit instructions), it is actually very practical to go with a simpler and more cost effective implementation. Not every application requires multi-threading or simultaneous 16/32 bit instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes my application was limited to 386, but one can extend this questions to x86-64 bit processor. The Intel's 15 byte limitation seems to be an arbitrary number. Without it, the instructions can be infinitely long because prefixes can be repeated.

Comment: Your hypothetical instruction set does little to reduce the cost of decoding instructions while severely crippling it. The 8086, which decoded most of these prefixes, only had 20,000 transistors. In a modern x86 CPU design the entire decoder takes up a tiny amount of the die space. Why would anyone use your instruction set? No existing code will run on it, no existing compiler will generate correct code for it. Why not use an instruction set like ARM, one that was designed from the start to be simpler and more cost effective? Your hypothetical CPU will never exist.

Answer (score 3):

On 80386 that would be **11** bytes:

- Opcode:       1 byte
- MOD/RM:       1 byte
- SIB:          1 byte
- Displacement: 4 bytes
- Immediate:    4 bytes

The 2-byte opcodes are using the 0Fh instruction prefix which obviously is a prefix.

Comment: You can argue that the "escape byte" is part of the opcode, not an optional prefix.  Intel Atom decodes slowly on insns with more than 3 prefixes, *not* counting escape bytes.  However, Intel Silvermont is the exception: "Unlike most other processors from Intel and AMD, the Silvermont includes not
only the standard prefixes in this limitation, but also escape bytes such as `0F`",  according to Agner Fog's microarch doc.  So Silvermont is weird, and most CPUs don't count `0F` or `0F 38` as prefixes.  Calling them "escape bytes" seems sensible enough.